# Mysql subquery in select issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue with this query:

```
SELECT ea.date AS date,
            ea.locale AS geo,
            ea.adv_id AS adv_id,
            adv.name AS adv_name,
            ea.srcid AS srcid,
            (IFNULL(
                (SELECT g.pub_rate FROM rates_pub AS g WHERE g.adv_id = ea.adv_id AND g.pub_id=ea.pub_id AND g.geo=ea.locale g.created_on = (SELECT MAX(t.created_on) FROM rates_pub t WHERE t.adv_id = ea.adv_id AND t.pub_id = ea.pub_id AND t.geo = ea.locale AND t.created_on <= ea.date)),
                0
            )),
    
            sum(ea.count) AS count
            FROM events_aggr AS ea
            LEFT JOIN lookups.advertisers adv
            ON adv.id = ea.adv_id
            WHERE ea.date >= '2015-12-01' AND ea.date <= '2015-12-02' AND event = 5
            GROUP BY ea.date,ea.adv_id,ea.srcid,ea.locale
            ORDER BY ea.date,ea.adv_id,ea.locale;
```

I get an error messege:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'g.created_on = (SELECT MAX(t.created_on) FROM rates_pub t WHERE t.adv_id = ea.ad' at line 7

do you have any ideas why it doesnt work

thanks,

Comment: `WHERE AND` remove AND before `ea.date`

Comment: Don't you just miss AND before g.created_on?

Comment: Ok, I removed it still the issue remains :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seem  you have missing an `AND`

```
(IFNULL(
        (SELECT g.pub_rate FROM rates_pub AS g 
            WHERE g.adv_id = ea.adv_id 
            AND g.pub_id=ea.pub_id 
            AND g.gea=ea.locale 
    here ????? g.created_on = (SELECT MAX(t.created_on) 
                   FROM rates_pub t  
                   WHERE t.adv_id = ea.adv_id 
                   AND t.pub_id = ea.pub_id 
                   AND t.geo = ea.locale 
                   AND t.created_on <= ea.date)),
            0
        )), .......
```

Comment: And `WHERE AND ea.date >= '2015-12-01' AND ea.date <= '2015-12-02' AND event = 5` There are multiple errors in query + SELECT list and GROUP BY column list does not correspond so the result may vary between executions.

Answer (score 1):

You miss something at

```
g.gea=ealocale g.created_on
```